# 途中まで同じノード配下の要素を XPath で取得したい

Tags: python, xpath

Python3でSeleniumを使ってChromeを自動操作しています。
ページを読み込む度にxpathが変化するので、for文で回してテキストが一致するものを取得しています。

例えばxpathが

```xml
//*[@id="aa"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[100]/div[4]/div/span
```

のものを、テキストの一致で取得できた場合、

```xml
//*[@id="aa"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[100]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/span
```

という

```xml
//*[@id="aa"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[100]/div[4]
```

の部分まで同じ要素を取得することは可能でしょうか？

ちなみに毎回変化するのは div[100] の部分で、それ以外は両要素ともxpathは変化しません。

```py
elm2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="aa"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div[4]/div/span')

for x in elm2:
    if x.text == "猫":
        print(x.text)
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようにやってみてください。

```
elm2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="aa"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[*]/div[4]/div/span')

for x in elm2:
    if x.text == "猫":
        print(x.text)
        elm3 = x.find_elements_by_xpath('../../div[3]/div[2]/span')
            ...
```